# Evaluating Ruby and Mongo performance: 1.6M small records in file, takes 15 min to write 800K records to Mongo? More efficient way?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

We have 1.6M records in a flat file. Each record contains three or four short strings of fewer than 100 characters.

We only need 800K of these records. We write these records to a Mongo collection. The other 800K are ignored.

It takes about 15 min to process the file, meaning we process about 1.67K records/second. Is this expected performance, or should the process be much faster (e.g., 5K records/second, 10K records/second)?

Code below (@skip is a hash of about 800K app IDs).

```
def updateApplicationDeviceTypes(dir, limit)
  puts "Updating Application Data (Pass 3 - Device Types)..."
  file = File.join(dir, '/application_device_type')
  cols = getColumns(file)
  device_type_id_col = cols[:device_type_id]

  update = Proc.new do |id, group|
    @applications_coll.update(
      { "itunes_id" => id },
      { :$set => { "devices" => group } }
      # If all records for one id aren't adjacent, you'll need this instead
      #{ :$addToSet => { "devices" => { :$each => group } } }
    ) unless !id or @skip[id.intern]
  end
  getValue = Proc.new { |r| r[device_type_id_col] }

  batchRecords(file, cols[:application_id], update, getValue, limit)
end

# result to an array, before calling "update" on the array/id
def batchRecords(filename, idCol, update, getValue, limit=nil)
  current_id    = nil
  current_group = []

  eachRecord(filename, limit) do |r|
    id    = r[idCol]
    value = getValue.call(r)

    if id == current_id and !value.nil?
      current_group << value
    else
      update.call(current_id, current_group) unless current_id.nil?
      current_id    = id
      current_group = value.nil? ? [] : [value]
    end
  end

  # Since the above is only called once for each row, we still
  # have one group to update.
  update.call(current_id, current_group)
end
```

Comment: Your performance depends on: Number and Speed of Cpu's, size of Caches, Size of memory, speed of IO subsystem / disks. What makes you think we could judge your performance knowing only one parameter ( the programming language )

Comment: Sorry, @Klaus. Assume development is being done on a standard Macbook Pro.

Comment: specific specs: 
Processor: 2.26 Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo
Memory: 4GB 1067 Mhz DDR3
Hard drive: 500 GB, 5400 RPM

Comment: the most important information - how are you writing them to this collection?  are there any indexes?  The disk is pretty slow - I'm going to bet that your limiting factor will be IO bandwidth (the writes have to be fsync'ed to disk and your disk only supports so many IOPs).  You can use 'mongoperf' tool available in your mongo distro to test exact limits of IOPS on your machine.

Comment: yes, there are indices. we are updating, not inserting. as far as we know, there are no batch updates available in mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Schema design and the read and write patterns of your application play an extremely large role in your applications performance.

I'd recommend enabling the profiler before looking at machine and IO level performance:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

You may also find these talks from last year's MongoSV useful:

http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv-2012/lessons-field-performance-operations
http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv-2012/mongodb-performance-tuning

Comment: Thanks, Brandon. We updated the question with our method. It's very simple, reading from a file (not DB) and writing to Mongo.